# Return user object after auth to parent page w/o refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

So I've finally got my routes set up and my Soundcloud Authentication is working great.  The problem that I'm now having is that I can't figure out how to return a user to the parent page without refreshing.  What I have done so far is created a pop up so that the user can authenticate.  This redirects to the Soundcloud callback that I have specified.  I then redirect that callback to a callback i've made so I can close the pop up window.

If I try to make any actions on the page after authentication it keeps bringing up the Connect With Soundcloud page, until I refresh the page.  After the page is refreshed it returns the user and everything fine and dandy.

Here's the function on the frontend:

```
var windowObjectReference;
var strWindowFeatures = "width=420,height=230,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=1";

function allowLike(){
  $('.queueTrack').off('click').on('click', function(){

    console.log('clicked like');
    thisDiv = $(this);
    $.getJSON('/user', function(data){

      var token = data.token;
      songId = thisDiv.data("songid");

      $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites/' + songId + '?oauth_token=' + token,
            type: 'PUT',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('u liked' + songId)
            },
            error: function(){
              windowObjectReference = window.open("/auth/soundcloud", "SC_Connect", strWindowFeatures);
            } 
        });
    }).error(function(){
      console.log('getJSON error');
      windowObjectReference = window.open("/auth/soundcloud", "SC_Connect", strWindowFeatures);
    });
  })
}
```

And on the backend I have the following:

```
router.get('/auth/soundcloud/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('soundcloud', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/after-auth.html');
  });
```

The after-auth.html closes the pop up fine, but I can't figure out how to return the user object to the parent page without refreshing.

I have seen a tutorial that uses Angular to do this, but is it possible without using Angular?

Comment: Can you share your code or create a plunker?

Comment: @BrianBaker Code added

Comment: Oops I thought you were using Angular and I had a whole writeup ready :)

Comment: @BrianBaker ah, thanks for checking it out anyway! I know it's possible with Angular and i'm sure it's possible w/o too, but just not sure.  Gonna keep trying

Comment: Either way passport should return a user object for you to pass back to the frontend like `passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info)`. Then you would update the user model in the ajax success function.

Comment: @BrianBaker yep it actually works as intended.  Was an issue with using localhost vs http://127.0.0.1 to access the site

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that my code is actually doing what is intended. I couldn't figure out why it would sometimes work.

The solution (well, problem) was that I was accessing the site via localhost.  Apparently this does not guarantee the same IP address at all times.  Instead, if I access the site via http://127.0.0.1, it works great and is able to access the user object as intended.

For anyone working with something similar, be sure to continually use http://127.0.0.1 and not localhost to remain consistent.  I think this has caused me problems in the past as well but I was not aware of at the time.